# Fhir - data entry operator / Audit

Tags: hl7-fhir

I have been trying to find out a resource in fhir to represent  data entry operators. What is the closest matched resource to represent a data entry operator in fhir ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practitioner.  Practitioner is used for any human (or occasionally animal) who is acting in their professional capacity.  So while it includes clinicians, it also includes receptionists, taxi drivers, etc.  If you're doing something primarily because it's your job rather than because you have some sort of friendship/personal relationship with the patient, you use Practitioner.